# How do I word a polite notice about toilets in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin, usage, vocabulary

My friend has asked me how to translate a sign asking people using a bathroom (toilet) at the tourist attraction where she works. She wants to ask that they do not to throw toilet paper in the wastebin/basket but instead to put it in the toilet bowl (and flush).

I'm not good at formal Chinese, but I've done a little research and have come up with this as a suggestion. Could you let me know if it's OK?

请勿将卫生纸入篓

卫生纸应扔进马桶

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written pretty well, I would just suggest switching the order...first sentence last, last sentence first

Answer (score 0):

It's OK mainly, unless missing "to flush".

Just as a suggestion:

请将卫生纸扔进马桶并冲掉
请勿扔进纸篓

Answer (score 0):

My recommend are

Traditional Chinese - "使用過衛生紙請直接沖入馬桶".

Simplified Chinese - "使用过厕纸请直接冲入马桶".